# get inventory status returning 'No'

Tags: inventory, status

```
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'tlb1');
        $invStatus = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_inventory_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

I quick log of the $invStatus says that the value is always set to 'No'.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attribute seems to be unaccessible without first loading the product itself, so below achieves optimal product inventory status accentuation.

**- edited for logical and efficient loading**

```
$productSku = 'tlb1';

$product = Mage::registry('product_' . $productSku);
if (!$product) {
    // Load product by sku
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->load($product->getIdBySku($productSku));

    // Put in registry for next load
    Mage::register('product_' . $productSku, $product);

    // Load the attribute and set its data once
    $product->setData('product_inventory_status_value', $product->getResource()
        ->getAttribute('product_inventory_status')
        ->getFrontend()
        ->getValue($product));
}

// Here is the data for re-use
$invStatus = $product->getData('product_inventory_status_value');
```

Comment: This is a slow load, you load the product fist(but not fully) and do the same again by your `load()` (which is also incorrect because you need to give the id to load. `catalog/product` has a extra method `->getIdBySky('tlb1`)` which is a lot faster. Also if you need the data more than once, be sure to put the product in `Mage::registry`

Answer (score 2):

According to your code,`product_inventory_status` is not `a product attribute`.It is not `a inventory field`.

For getting inventory,please try this.

```
$product->getStockItem()->getData();

$product->getStockItem()->getData('status');
```

If `loadByAttribute()` do not provide data then then you need load product model by id

Comment: Ah, found a solution I'll post later -- thanks anyway Amit! (ps.  I had  to call load on the model before I could get it's inventory status) :D